# Django AdminSite - Difficult or Easy Implementation?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Has anyone implemented their own AdminSite? How easy/hard was the basic implementation?

I'm in the midst of building a "cms" that's going to be quite large and decently complex in some areas and I'm wondering if using something like AdminSite would save some time. I'd rather not have to make my own implementation for admin actions and inlines and the like (I know I can just use inline forms but that's not as simple as inlines = [Foo]).

When using a custom AdminSite, is further customization equivalent to customizing the standard Django admin?

Comment: "wondering if using something like AdminSite would save some time"?  It totally saves mountains of time.  Perhaps that's not what you're really asking.  You might want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've read the [admin site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) docs. It's a lengthy document, but two main hooks for adding custom functionality is through custom urls and modified standard views in your own `AdminSite` and `ModelAdmin` objects. Once you hook those in and the urls get mapped, it's just like building any other Django application, only that the templates aren't yours, so they're are a bit hard to manage and take getting used to. But it allows you to do additional gymnastics, like adding a [form wizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) to the admin site or splitting everything into multiple forms and rendering them in a single HTML `form` element in the templates, doing custom handling of `GET`/`POST` requests, etc.

I've used it in the past to create views for displaying custom reports and to create custom editing scenarios for the staff. My opinion is that you should KISS as much as possible. The admin site is all about generic views and generic presentation. Do expand, but be cautious if you override template blocks and think twice before you override something that's not wrapped in a block. Certain admin site features have certain presentation assumptions and the JS client app that's shipped with Django makes some too (that's what I've figured when working with adding dynamic inline models way back), so it'd be quite an undertaking if you'd like to roll a completely different presentation.

The answer in any case is YES! The admin site will provide you with more features for managing your model data interactively. I don't know how extensively you'd need to customize the admin, but there are CMSs, dedicated admin apps and admin integrated apps that are a real eye-opener. [Django CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/), as I recalled, has been praised as the best open-source Django CMS out there and from what I can see it rolls it's own cust change/list views. [Rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) is an admin site only app that allows you to edit your translation files interactively and has an exhaustive admin interface! If you shop around on bitbucket and github you'll find many more examples, it should help you figure out best how much effort you'd need to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

**Both**

If you are OK with it not doing exactly what you want its pretty much done for you automatically. If you need fine grain control over certain things it can be hard to customize without knowing the internals of the admin code.

Answer (score 0):

the django admin is more of a one size fits all kind of ui which may not be intuitive for use in some cases .. 
customizing its look is easy but extending it is some how hard. you are better off designing your own views in that case.